# AWS QuickSight how to combine fields from multiple datasets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to use columns from different datasets when defining a calculated field?
Something like this:
`sum({sales.refund_amount})+sum({refunds.refund_amount})`

For example, I have two datasets, each with an amount and date columns:

1. sales: sale_amount, sale_date
2. refunds: refund_amount, refund_date

My goal is to create a visual which sums the sales and refunds amount for the selected date range. Is there any way to do this without creating a new dataset and join the tables?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  I think you'd need to create a new dataset that defines how the two datasets are combined to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly you can't. A visual in QuickSight can use fields from only one dataset.